# Service Fabric Remote Debugging

Tags: c#, azure, azure-service-fabric

Can anybody point me what I'm doing wrong? For the last couple of days, I'm trying to remotely debug my application on Service Fabric and I get to the moment when I see this :

[image]

I can select service from Cloud Explorer => Attach Debugger but no matter what I do I always see the error "There was a failure ....." I've disabled my firewall rules, LB on azure enables the traffic and I'm really stuck here.

Can anybody help?

Comment: I found the easiest way to actually debug was to install VS on the cluster machines.

Comment: If we are talking about on prem cluster I believe this is not possible.

Comment: No this is deployed on Azure. I just want to attach debugger remotely to service that is running inside Azure Service Fabric to check something

Comment: Have you installed the remote debugger? The remote debugger must also be running before you can attach I believe. You can download it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging?view=vs-2017